# macOS - Remove remembered WiFi network connections

Tags: networking, connection

I have a MacBook Pro I want to delete all networks in my settings except for the one in my own home to stop the laptop from trying to connect to other networks

Answer (score 0):

Two separate issues, but start from the same place...

System Prefs > Network > WiFi

1. To prevent it attempting to join unknown networks, uncheck 'Ask to join new networks'

[image]

2. To remove any existing networks, click Advanced, bottom right, then the WiFi tab.
   You can multi-select in the list using shift or ctrl click, then use the  <kbd>-</kbd>  button to remove

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work, cannot delete the networks already listed. Am a bit paranoid now because of where I am living.......

Comment: Works perfectly here & has done for years. I frequently trim temporary connections, coffee shops etc from there. Are you on some kind of limited account? Non-admin, parental controlled, etc?